# Design a field value verification (not odoo.api.constrains validation)

Tags: python, odoo

Class Diagram:

```
   ,-------------------.    
   | question_request  |   
   |-------------------|    
   | +Char Name        |    
   | +Char LastName    |    
   | +Integer Age      |    
   | +Text Description |    
   |-------------------|    
   `-------------------'
```

Code

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

  class Request(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.request'
    _description = "Request"
    
    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name", required=True)
    age = fields.Integer(string="Age", required=True)
    description = fields.Text()
```

Goal:

Feature for field's value manual verification by users.

Ex: Customer send a request with field's values as follow:​

```
Name:     "Peterrrrrrrrrr"
LastName: "Smith"
Age:      150
```

An employee user would be able to inform to the customer about the wrong values as follows:

```
Name:     State=Invalid, Comment="Probably Typo error"
LastName: State=Valid
Age:      State=Invalid, Comment="Confirm real age"
```

It's not a feature about value validation (odoo.api.constrains(*args)), but about manual values verification by an user (abcde is a **valid** value for the *name* field, but an user need to **confirm** or **verify** that).

The first idea was to use an extra field for verification and another extra field for the comment

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

  class Request(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.request'
    _description = "Request"
    
    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name", required=True)
    age = fields.Integer(string="Age", required=True)
    description = fields.Text() 
    
    # fields for verification
    name_verification = fields.Selection([
      ('valid', 'Valid'),
      ('invalid', 'Invalid'),
      ('notverified', 'Not verified')
    ], default="notverified")
    name_verification_comment = fields.Text()
```

​
But this is not a good approach because the need of implementing the 'field_value_verification' for each field and each model which need the verification feature.
So I thought to store the 'field_value_verification' in the 'FieldsVerification' related model as follows:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

  class Request(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.request'
    _description = "Request"
    
    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name", required=True)
    age = fields.Integer(string="Age", required=True)
    description = fields.Text() 
    fueld_verification_ids = ???
    
  class FieldsVerification(models.Model): 
    _name = 'test.fields_verification'
    _description = "Verification"
    
    class_name = fields.Char(strng="Class")
    record_id = ???
    field_name = fields.Char(string="Field")
    status = fields .Selection([
      ('valid', 'Valid'),
      ('invalid', 'Invalid'),
      ('notverified', 'Not verified')
    ], default="notverified")
```

​
Just right here I got stuck, so I thought to ask to the community.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code , it may help you.

```
from odoo.exceptions import UserError
from odoo import api, _

@api.constrains('field_name')
def field_name_constratints(self):

if your condition:
 raise UserError(_('Your Message!'))
```

For example  , in the case of the field `age`

```
@api.constrains('age')
def age_constratints(self):

if self.age > 80 or self.age < 10:
   raise UserError(_('Confirm your real age !'))
```

Also don't forget to import the `UserError` and `_`

Comment: Thanks for you answer. i'm not asking about validation but value verification by an user. Maybe don't explain it well. I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, I'd suggest 2 possibilities.
Assume you have a form view displaying fields for user to input.

1. Create a button triggers a wizard window.
2. Another way is to override create() and write() method of the model to embed the wizard or any validation/condition formatting.

[ORM wizard explaination](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html#wizards)

**Example code for suggestion 1:**
Below is model

```
    class Request(models.Model):
        _name = 'test.request'
        _description = "Request"

        name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
        last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name", required=True)
        age = fields.Integer(string="Age", required=True)
        description = fields.Text()

        def call_wizard(self):
            view = self.env.ref('my_module.wizard_xml_id')
            wiz = self.env['verify.input'].create({})
            return {'name': _('Confirm Input?'),
                    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                    'view_type': 'form',
                    'view_mode': 'form',
                    'res_model': 'verify.input',
                    'views': [(view.id, 'form')],
                    'view_id': view.id,
                    'target': 'new',
                    'res_id': wiz.id,
                    'context': {'default_name': self.name,
                                'default_last_name': self.last_name,
                                'default_age': self.age,
                                'default_description': self.description}
                    }
```

Below is wizard

```
    class Verify(models.TransientModel):  
        _name = 'verify.input'
        name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
        last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name", required=True)
        age = fields.Integer(string="Age", required=True)
        description = fields.Text()
```

Create an xml view for the wizard to display how you want it.